# Is matter-wave a consequence of the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality

The position and momentum of a particle are undefined because of the uncertainty principle. Does this result in matter-wave with wavelength given by the following equation?

$ \lambda ={\frac {h}{mv}} $

Comment: Recommended resource: the discussion by Grant Sanderson (3blue1brown). Youtube video, titled, [The more general uncertainty principle, regarding Fourier transforms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4).

Answer (score 1):

No, these are two independent, though related, concepts.

A free particle has Hamiltonian $\hat{\,p}^2/2m$ so its state should be composed of eigenstates of the momentum operator:
$$
\hat{\,p} \, |p \rangle = p | p \rangle \; \rightarrow \; -i \hbar \frac{d}{dx} \langle x | p \rangle = p \langle x | p \rangle \;  \rightarrow \; \phi_p(x) = \langle x | p \rangle = A \exp\left( i \frac{p}{\hbar} x\right)
$$
whose wavefunctions thus have associated wavelengths $\lambda = \frac{2 \pi}{k} = \frac{2 \pi}{p/\hbar} = h/p$. But you can see that these eigenfunctions are not normalizable:
$$
\langle p | p \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi_p^*(x)\, \phi_p(x) \, dx = |A|^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 \, dx = \infty
$$
To construct normalizable, and thus physically realizable, states, we must find continuous superpositions of these momentum eigenstates
$$
\psi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(p) \, \phi_p(x) \, dp
$$
which are called wavepackets. Assuming a Gaussian form for $f(p)$ yields a Gaussian form of $\psi(x)$, because the above integral is actually just a Fourier transform.  By calculating $\sigma_p$ and $\sigma_x$ from such a Gaussian wavepacket state one can see that it is a "minimum uncertainty" state, i.e., $\sigma_x \sigma_p = \hbar/2$ (although under time evolution this product will grow).

So, the de Broglie wavelength, $\lambda_p = h/p$, is simply the wavelength associated to a single momentum eigenstate. But that state is not normalizable, and therefore there exist no definite-momentum (or definite-energy) free particles. A free particle has no single de Broglie wavelength.  Instead one must construct wavepackets that contain a spectrum of momentum values (a spectrum of de Broglie wavelengths) and the momentum and position distributions of such wavepackets obey the uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 1):

The de Broglie wavelength directly comes out of the Einstein-Planck energy condition:
\begin{equation*}
E = h f  
\end{equation*}

where $h$ is Planck's constant and $f$ is the frequency of a given particle.

Planck discovered this in 1900 when determining the correct density of states for black-body radiation, and Einstein made the connection in 1905 that this energy condition was related to the particle description of light, i.e. photons.

Given that the magnitude for a single photon's 4-momentum is zero,
\begin{equation*}
p_\mu p^\mu = E^{2} - (pc)^{2} = m^{2}c^{4} = 0,
\end{equation*}

then $|E| = |p|c$. Subsituting this into the Planck-Einstein energy formula yields the de Broglie wavelength. As you can see, this has no reference to uncertainty relations as a starting condition. It simply comes from a combination of quantized energy and relativity. It, however, is related as seen in @Ben H's answer

Answer (score 1):

> Is matter-wave a consequence of the uncertainty principle?

#### Short answer

No, it is rather the other way round:
The uncertainty principle is a consequence of the matter-wave nature.

#### Longer answer

The video "[The more general uncertainty principle, regarding Fourier
transforms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4)" (already recommended by a comment below your question)
does a great job in intuitively explaining the uncertainty principle
between time ($t$) and frequency ($f$).
It says that a narrow packet in time necessarily corresponds
to a wide packet in frequency, and vice versa.
However, the video doesn't give the mathematical formulation of this
[Fourier uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle):
$$\Delta t\ \Delta f \ge \frac{1}{4\pi} \tag{1}$$

There is a similar Fourier uncertainty principle between position
($x$) and the reciprocal wavelength ($1/\lambda$):
$$\Delta x\ \Delta \frac{1}{\lambda} \ge \frac{1}{4\pi} \tag{2}$$

So far, only mathematics (the Fourier transform) was involved, but no physics.
You get something physical by adding [de Broglie's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) which says
that every particle (with momentum $p$) behaves like a wave with wavelength
$$\lambda=\frac{h}{p} \tag{3}$$

By combining the Fourier uncertainty principle (2) with
de Broglie's relation (3) you get
$$\Delta x\ \Delta p \ge \frac{h}{4\pi} \tag{4}$$
which is [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) between position
($x$) and momentum ($p$).